# Create DSN with Wix

Tags: wix, odbc, dsn

Having trouble making a System DSN via Wix

here is my test code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Product Id="*" Name="TestProduct" Language="1033" Version="0.0.0.1" Manufacturer="WixEdit" UpgradeCode="*">
        <Package Description="Test file in a Product" Comments="Simple test" InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" />
        <Media Id="1" Cabinet="simple.cab" EmbedCab="yes" />
        <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
            <Component Id="C_PROD_DSN" Guid="*">
                <ODBCDataSource Id="Prod_Dsn" Name="SomeName" Registration="machine" DriverName="ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server">
                    <Property Id="Description" Value="Some Description" />
                    <Property Id="Database" Value="SomeDB" />
                    <Property Id="Language" Value="us_english" />
                    <Property Id="LastUser" Value="SomeUser" />
                    <Property Id="Driver" Value="C:\windows\system32\msodbcsql11.dll" />
                </ODBCDataSource>
            </Component>
        </Directory>
        <Feature Id="DefaultFeature" Title="Main Feature" Level="1">
            <ComponentRef Id="C_PROD_DSN" />
        </Feature>
        <UI />
    </Product>
</Wix>
```

Wix Edit compiles it just fine but when i run it I get

> Error configuring ODBC data source: SomeName. ODBC error 6: Component not found in the registry. Verify that the file SomeName exists and that you can access it.

This is a DSN to a SQL DB not to a file.

I know I can make this work by just building up the Registry trees I need, I just like to try it using what should be the built in functionality for the task.

Can this be done using ODBCDataSource? (without Custom Actions, I just don't have time to write another one right now) or should I just cut my losses and do it with RegistryKey and RegistryValue?